# Server options for Implementing long polling in python to an Android client

Tags: android, python, http, webserver, long-polling

I've a python program that currently listens for a bunch of progress events. I want to send these events back to an Android client preferably using HTTP long polling.

I'm looking for "simple" python-based web server that allow me to quickly integrate this existing Python code and implement long polling.

Comment: If you are looking for Python microframeworks, you could look at Flask (which has a lot more extensions), Bottle, etc. You have to look for something that's able to do nonblocking stuff, etc. You might consider using node.js instead.

Comment: I need something in python only. I'll have a look at Flask.